# Location of exported notes from Note Everything app

Tags: files, notes

Where can I find the exported notes file from the [Note Everything](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.softxperience.android.noteeverything) app on Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Note Everything](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.softxperience.android.noteeverything) exports all notes in the folder named `noteeverything`. It seems that it chooses `/sdcard` as its base to identify where to store. Regardless of it, in my device having External SD card as default storage, the notes were saved in the root directory of external SD card under the folder named `noteeverything/text/` with names as `text[0-9]+_<Note_Title>.txt`.

E.g.:

```
text7_Bonafide.txt
text6_Bcode.txt
text5_QW.txt
```

where QW, Bcode, and Bonafide are the respective titles of my notes.

You can also find other used resources under the folder `noteeverything`.

Ultimately, you should look under all your storages for this folder. Otherwise, just use find/search in your File Manger to do the job for you.

A simple command-line query would be `find /storage -iname noteeverything`.